# How to check if a key already exists in the database using Firebase and Python?

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, optimization

Essentially, I'll be using a database of this structure:

[image: Database structure]

to keep track of the users' xp. Under the `xp_data` section, there will be multiple timestamps and xp numbers for each timestamp. A function will run every 24 hours, that will log the users' XP. I want to have some way to check if the player is already in the database (and if so, add to their existing xp count) and if not, create a new node for them. Here is my code for writing to the server:

```
db_ref = db.reference('/')

for i in range(100):

    tom = await mee6API.levels.get_leaderboard_page(i)

    if xp_trigger:
        break
    
    this_lb_list = {}

    for l in tom['players']:
        if l['xp'] < 300:
            xp_trigger = True
            break
        
        this_lb_list.update({l['id']: {'name': l['username'], 'xp_data': {time.strftime(time_format_str, time.gmtime()): l['xp']}}})

        details += [{ int(l['id']) : l['xp']}]

    print(i)

    db_ref.update(this_lb_list)
```

Basically, this code loops through each page in the leaderboard, obtains the XP for each user, and appends it to a dict, which is then used to update the database. there are two problems with this code, one is that it does not check if the user already exists, meaning that, and this is the second problem, that it overwrites the user's existing data. I've also attempted to write the data for each player individually, but problem 1 was still an issue, and it was painfully slow. What can I do to rectify this?

Comment: How is a user identified in your database, and in your code?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen They're identified based on their ID, which is the top-level number you see in the database.

Comment: Thanks, I think I get the problem now. Let me write up a quick answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass a value for a property in `update()`, that value replaces the entire existing value of the property in the database. So while `update()` leaves the properties you *don't* specify in the call unmodified, it does completely replace any property you *do* specify.

To add a value to an existing property, you'll want to specify the entire path as the key, separating the various child nodes with `/`.

So something like:

```
this_lb_list.update({'xp_data/13-Auth-2021': l['xp']})
```

This will write only the `13-Auth-2021` of `xp_data`, leaving all other child nodes of `xp_data` unmodified.

You'll of course want to use a variable for the date/time, but the important thing is that you specify it in the key, and not in the value of the dictionary.

Comment: This solution does work for when the user is in the database, but I still need some way to detect if the user does not exist yet. Are you aware. of a way to do this?

Comment: To know if there is a data for a user, you'll have to read that data.

Comment: This should work, yes?
`try:
    tp_ref = db.reference(str(l['id']))
    x = tp_ref.get()
    lb_list_existing.update(
    {
        f"{l['id']}/xp_data/{time.strftime(time_format_str, time.gmtime())}" : l['xp']
    })
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    this_lb_list.update({l['id']: {'name': l['username'], 'xp_data' : {time.strftime(time_format_str, time.gmtime()): l['xp']}}})`
However, even though the user doesn't exist, the `try` part doesn't seem to return an error.